# Invalid or corrupt jarfile /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get a grasp of unitTesting and have set out to follow this [netTuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-selenium-2-with-phpunit/). In the tutorial it gets you to download a javafile from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). This file is then moved and then using

`java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar`

the file is meant to run.

My problem is that I get the message

`Invalid or corrupt jarfile /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar`

The searches I have made to resolve this issue talk about people creating their own file or something going wrong with the download as the file size should be bigger than what has been downloaded. Mine is 34.6MB which is what I believe to be about correct. I have also checked what Java version I am running (1.6.0_65), ([here](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10931425) says 1.6+ is fine).

This appears to be a common problem, but I have not been able to find any solutions.

Comment: Just semantics here, but selenium is not for unit testing.  Unit testing is actually testing that uses the actual classes and tests throughput.  Selenium covers the front end UI.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I thought it was different frameworks to cover the goal. Obviously I still have a lot to learn

Comment: if you're using java, maybe you should check out http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium . it's a java framework using selenium 2 that has been used in actual full-scale regression builds.  it should help you get right up and started pumping out scripts!

Answer (score 7):

After trying a number of different options (including re-downloading on several occasions) it seems the file WAS corrupt.

I downloaded from [here instead](https://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-2.33.0.zip) and it worked first time.

Comment: Replacing the file worked for me as well.  Found a replacement at http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html which fixed an issue with Protractor's default build.

Comment: Thx, this resolved the `Invalid or corrupt` error when attempting to run the npm installed **protractor** with `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start --standalone` The fix was just to copy the desired jar from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html with: `curl http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -o node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar`

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue on Mac for selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar because of a bug https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/370.

If someone is still facing the issue after trying all the solutions mentioned above, easiest way to get it working is to run the command with version(latest - stable).

**sudo webdriver-manager --versions.standalone=3.9.1 update**

then to start webdriver -

**sudo webdriver-manager --versions.standalone=3.9.1 start**

where 3.9.1 is version.
Apart from this also check for correct Java version

Answer (score 2):

I was behind a corporate firewall when this corrupt file was created. I'm using OSX. For me, removing the file then re-downloading with proxy setting provided solved the problem.

```
1) sudo rm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar
2) sudo webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://<your proxy server>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't need to use the --proxy

Answer (score 2):

On mac, I had to sudo on both.

- sudo npm install -g protractor
- sudo webdriver-manager update

Else it would give me the corrupt jar error, no need for proxy

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It was corrupt and I just removed the .jar and did a webdriver-manager update again and got a new working .jar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this worked for me in windows.

In the command prompt, type the following commands in order.

1. webdriver-manager clean --out_dir
2. webdriver-manager update

Answer (score 0):

Replace the file from here:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

I downloaded the file from here and replaced it in my selenium folder.